# Extjs4 filtering grids with same store

Tags: grid, extjs4, filtering, store

I have a tab panel, which contains tow tabs, `Tab1` and `Tab2`.
`Tab1` contains a grid panel and a button to filter this grid according to a specific character.
`Tab2` contains the same grid.
The probem is when I filter the grid in `Tab1`, I don't want that the grid in `Tab2` will be filtered because they are independent!
What is happened is logic because the two grids have the same store, but can I separate the filtering effect on the two grids.

**Solution**

I need to create an instance of the store, I'm declaring it like this:

```
{
     xtype: 'grid',
     store: 'theStore'
     // Rest of the properties
}
```

What I need to do is the following:
create an instance of the store: `var My_Store = Ext.create('App.store.MyStore');`
then:

```
{
    xtype: 'grid',
    store:My_Store
    //column definitions etc...   
}​
```

This creates a unique instance of the store, if I reference the store like this: store: 'MyStore' I just get the same store, and when I sort, page, filter, ... all the stores do the same.

Comment: Is there a question here?